# textbox input as column header in listview and table column in vb6 and mysql

Tags: mysql, database, listview, vb6, columnheader

Is it possible to make the input of textbox as column header in listview and table column in mysql?

I want to make something like this:

```
textbox: name

listview columnheader: name

table column: name
```

another input:

```
textbox: year

listview columnheader: name    year

table column: name    year
```

How to achieve this one? I can't search this on net. Just asking if this is possible in vb6 and mysql as database. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add columns dynamically using the [`ListViewColumnHeaders.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443195%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), something like:

```
ListView.ColumnHeaders.Add , , Text1.Text, 2000, lvwColumnLeft
```

The first two parameters (omitted in my sample) allow you to specify the index (to control the position) and an optional key value to refer to the column later on.

Comment: What if I want to add columnheaders from database dynamically, is it also possible?

Comment: @HandyManny Yes, just enumerate the table columns and repeat that line with each name

Comment: can you provide examples or update you answer? Sorry but I can't seem to get what you meant.  Really having hard time when it's from database.

Comment: @HandyManny Not without knowing more about how you're accessing the database, ideally with some sample code in your question.

Comment: Is it also possible to add tables in mysql dynamically? Based from my post, instead of in listview, I want in column in my table in database.

Comment: Using your method, how can i permanently make the columnheader permanent? it looks like, when the application closes, The columnheader changes.

Comment: @HandyManny Adding columsn to a MySQL table is a completely different question wfor which you should [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). As for making it permanent, any form of settings like XML, ini file, registry, etc to save the column names then just re add them from that storage on startup.